# How should I align a USB Internet stick relative to the nearest cell tower in order to have the best signal?

Tags: internet-connection, dongle, usb-modem

I use a USB Internet stick of this kind:

[image]

To connect to the Internet, I simply insert a SIM card into this stick and then insert the stick into a USB port of my laptop.

Based on my experience of participating in Zoom video conferences with this Internet stick, it looks like the quality of the signal depends on the orientation of the stick.

So how should I align my Internet stick in order to have the best signal, from the practical standpoint? In the direction of the nearest cell tower? Or perpendicular to that direction? Or maybe at some angle?

Comment: Have you tried using a hotspot on your phone instead?

Comment: @Gantendo I haven't, for I don't have a smartphone. I have never bought a smartphone, in order to protect my eyes. So, I use laptops, a USB Internet stick, and a simple button phone :)

Comment: This is not a Physics forum. Are you asking for the best practical orientation, or for the best theoretical orientation. In the former case, please state it as such in your question, in the latter case, your question does not belong here (it does in [Physics StackExchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/)).

Comment: @ComputerUser121212 Thanks, I have edited my question. Of course, I want to know the best practical orientation. I just want the best signal.

Comment: This is a surprisingly complicated question because, if I am am correct, there are 4 different antennas in that tiny little thing.

Comment: @Gantendo If there are four antennas pointing in different directions, then I guess the direction should not really matter...

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/gAy3J9f.png  It may or may not be wise to just test it out in different orientations. Or buy a internet stick intended for long(er) range communication. Some of them have pretty big antennas on them. I have bookmarked the question because I am curious if someone will post a good answer.

Comment: Of bigger concern is what there is BETWEEN this device and the cellular tower. Large electrical equipment may interrupt, mask, or block signals. Being near windows isn't ONLY about cellular signals moving more easily through glass but also that electrical cables in the walls may mask signals. ACs and other appliances will have an impact. A neighbor being an amateur radio or CB operator and having poor antenna design, a crowd of people next door, and a myriad other factors will all impact your reception. I recommend a USB extension cable and placing the dongle high and adjusting as you can.

Comment: I have a USB stick like this (probably not the same model) and I have had it for some years. I use it cottage country where you do not know the location of the towers. it works fine.

Comment: Have a look at this article https://ravisiyer.wordpress.com/2017/09/06/how-to-get-precise-4g-signal-strength-rssi-for-huawei-usb-4g-dongle-for-windows-pc/. If you are able to get this signal strength information then you can test moving the dongle to different positions then wait 1-2 min and check signal quality